# Casting a String to an unsigned long int

Tags: c, casting

I encountered a bit of C code that does something like the following. Just wondering if someone could tell me exactly what's going on in this code, because I've never really encountered anything like this before. The line I care about is the one where path is given a value

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned long path;

    //...

    path = (unsigned long) "somevariable";


    return 0;
}
```

I tried searching around to figure this out, but I couldn't find anything that helped. Just wondering if someone could clarify what's going on. In particular, I'm wondering:

1. What is assigned to path? Is it a char * cast to an unsigned long?
2. If path is the address of the string "somevariable", then what is the scope of the string "somevariable"? Does it have scope local to the function init or does it have the same scope as path? And how is it allocated (automatic vs dynamic)?
3. If someone knows the section of the c standard that can be referred to to understand this, this would also be appreciated.

Comment: "*something* like the following" - *sigh*. chasing ghosts again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, it is a pointer value cast to `unsigned long`
2) The string literal is always statically allocated in a read-only memory
3) You can refer to the [Section 6.4.5 (String Literals)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5)

Comment: Thanks! Would I be able to read the value of path from outside the init function?

Comment: @MattSteadman Yes. The value assigned to a variable stays as long as it's not reassigned.

Comment: Yes, as it is statically allocated.

Comment: Detail: "string literal is always ... allocated in a read-only memory"  --> It might be read-only memory, it might not.  IAC, code should not attempt to write it - that is UB.

Comment: @chux Yeah, it *technically* might not restrict writing to it. But a write attempt will give an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can't cast string to unsigned long, you have to use a function like strtoul()

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtoul.htm

Comment: This isn't code that I would ever write (for that same reason). It's code that I encountered that I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Trash that site and it's examples. The only value of it is it's "coding ground".

Comment: "can't cast string to unsigned long".  Disagree as the C spec says "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type"  §6.3.2.3 6.  It is unclear  what OP's over-all goal may be.

Answer (score 0):

This code attempts to convert the address of the string to an `unsigned long` variable. It would fail on a LLP64 implementation, where a pointer is 64 bits wide and an `unsigned long` is only 32 bits wide, or any other compiler where a pointer is wider than a `long`.

The completely portable version that follows the standard to the letter would be `const uintptr_t path = (uintptr_t)(void*)"somevariable";`.  A `uintptr_t` (defined in `<stdint.h>`) is guaranteed to be able to store the bits of any `void*`, and any kind of pointer is guaranteed to have a conversion to `void*`.  This would still have several problems.  For example, two identical strings can have different addresses.

Without more context, we can't tell what this is meant to accomplish.